# Laravel 5: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to pass an array with the logged-in user's votes on the posts from the controller to the view but I keep getting this error

> in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-5\resources\views\subreddit\show.blade.php)

I have tried to use `lists()` but I got this error instead `Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::lists()`

Using `lists('post_id')` returns the same error in the title.

Controller

```
public function show(Subreddit $subreddit)
{
    $posts = Subreddit::findOrFail($subreddit->id)->posts()->get();
    $votes = Auth::user()->votes()->get(); //I have also tried lists()

    return view('subreddit/show')
        ->with('subreddit', $subreddit)
        ->with('posts', $posts)
        ->with('votes', $votes);
}
```

View

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    @if ($voted = in_array($post->id, $votes))
      {!! Form::open(['url' => 'votes', 'class' => 'votes']) !!}
    @endif
      <div class="upvote topic" data-post="{{ $post->id }}">
         <a class="upvote vote {{ $voted ? 'voted-on' : '' }}" data-value="1"></a>
         <span class="count">0</span>
         <a class="downvote vote {{ $voted ? 'downvoted-on' : '' }}" data-value="-1"></a>
      </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: FYI, you can change `Auth::user()->votes()->get()` to just `Auth::user()->votes` and `Subreddit::findOrFail($subreddit->id)->posts()->get()` to just `Subreddit::findOrFail($subreddit->id)->posts`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to convert your collection to array. Just append `toArray()` to your query like below, as 'toArray()' converts the collection into a plain PHP array:

```
 $votes = Auth::user()->votes()->get()->toArray();
```

Hope this help.

Comment: That gave me `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::to_array()` even though I have included `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` at the top.

Comment: is it `toarray()` without the underscore?

Comment: oops, it's `toArray()` not to_array(), corrected my answer

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Please update your answer so I can select it as the correct one. @ajameswolf can you please elaborate?

Comment: So you are only using one column, I assume that is why you were using the lists command. This can be achieved in less steps and cleaner code:
$posts = Subreddit::findOrFail($subreddit->id)->posts()->select('post_id')->get();

Untested, but should work.

Comment: posts is a query so long as you have used eloquents built in relationships and the get() has not been called, so you can modify that query in line.

Answer (score 10):

You can convert the collection to an array like other suggested using `toArray()` method. But i'd rather change

```
in_array($post->id, $votes)
```

to

```
$votes->contains($post->id)
```

#### Update

The above only works if `$votes` is a collection of IDs. Eg. when you use

```
$votes = Auth::user()->votes()->pluck('post_id');
```

However, with your current controller code you would need to use

```
$votes->contains('post_id', $post->id);
```

since `$votes` is a collection of `Vote` objects, and you only want to search in the `post_id` column/attribute.

Comment: `@if($votes->contains('votes_column_id', $post->id))`
Thanks for the advice. For me it only worked by entering the name of the column.

Answer (score 5):

I think pluck will solve your problem.

```
$voteIds = Auth::user()->votes()->get()->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, @Suren you save my hours